# Why edit link has been removed for me?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have edited some questions . After that I found that edit link under questions and answers are removed .why this happened and how solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should review your [edit suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4057416/mohsen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). On the first page, which shows 20 most recent suggestions, I see 9 rejected ones. This is a very poor ratio, so it is not surprising you are unable to edit now.

See: [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81681)

Comment: I have a *feeling* that post is outdated. OP has 5 rejections and 5 approvals in the last 7 days. By the formula `rejects - (approvals / 3)) >= 5`, we get 5 - 1 = 4. However, if we continue going back, we hit more rejections, which pushes the value up to `>=5`. I would imagine the formula looks at past x edits (as suggested in the comments) rather than just the last 7 days.

Comment: @Rob It's also possible the OP got a manual edit suspension from a moderator.